# What is the relationship between coherent states and quantum coherence?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, coherence

What is the relationship between [coherent states](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_states) and [quantum coherence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherence_%28physics%29#Quantum_coherence)? To me coherent states were only talked about in regard to Quantum Harmonic Oscillator, whereas coherence and decoherence on the other hand, mostly in regard to entanglement.

Comment: Coherence is a completely general problem and it has little, if anything to do with entanglement. You can have an incoherent state that is entangled and still observe the entanglement within the coherence length... examples would be two entangled spins (with magnetic moment) going trough weak random magnetic fields or entangled photons going trough fog.